# how to retrieve text from anchor href attribute in python

Tags: python, href

Let's say I have a link like this:

```
link = '<a href="some text">...</a>'
```

Is there any way I can retrieve the text from anchor href attribute so the result will be something like this:

```
hrefText = 'some text'
```

And thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way:

```
import re
print re.search('(?<=<a href=")[^"]+',link).group(0)
```

Or,

```
print re.search(r'<a\s+href="([^"]+)',link).group(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you could split or use a regular expression, for a more *modular* and *powerful* tool set, you could use

> BeautifulSoup: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Sample code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
link = '<a href="some text">...</a>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(link, "html.parser")
for anchor in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print anchor['href']
```

Alternatively, for a single function, you can do this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

def getHref( link ):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(link, "html.parser")
    return soup.find_all('a', href=True)[0]['href']
```

Comment: isn't it a bit overkill just to parse a single href link?

Comment: Although this is a smaller problem, many people reading this in the future may be trying to do a bit more scraping :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use bs4 and requests lib for this.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://examplesite.com/'
source = requests.get(url)
text = source.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")
for link in soup.findAll('a', {}):
   href = '' + link.get('href')
   title = link.string
   print("hrefText = ", href)
```

Hope this helps :)